# How to fix Windows 2008 R2 show less memory than available

Tags: windows-server-2008

I've got Win2008 R2 64bit installed on Dell R410 server with 8GB of RAM. Dell Open Manage shows 8GB total and 4GB available for use, In Windows Control Panel, System i see 64bit and 8GB of RAM while in Windows Task Manager at Performance tab there is 4GB of memory available.

Dell support has made some checks and told me that if BIOS shows 8Gb of RAM and indeed BIOS does then it's operational system issue. Tried to search online for resolution but none found.

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could also be the BIOS memory configuration on the R410. All Dell's mid range and up 11G servers support three memory modes -

1. Optimized, where all RAM is made available to the CPU's using all available memory controller channels (up to 3 if available in your server, the R410 only supports 2 per CPU)
2. Advanced ECC mode which only enables
   2  and provides enhanced error correction.
3. Mirror Mode which again only uses 2
   channels and mirrors the contents so
   you only get half the amount of RAM
   available to the OS.

What you describe looks like Mirror mode is enabled to me, 8GB is installed and mirroring reduces that to 4GB made visible to the OS.

Comment: Haven't checked BIOS yet but probably you are more aware of whats going on that Dell support team... I will inform them so next time they won't waste my time...

thanks Helvick, you are pro !!!

Answer (score 0):

Is that 4GB Available in Task manager, or 4GB Total Physical Memory?

You may well only have 4GB Availaible of the 8GB Total on account of the system taking near 1/2 for Cache. This is normal for Windows, and the Cache memory will be freed as necessary for application use.

Comment: Physical Memory (MB) box

Total 4085
Cached 2500
Free 0

Answer (score 0):

Setting Up Dell Server Memory:

Start up your Dell Server

1. F2 = System Settings
2. Memory Settings 
   (Enter)
3. Memory Operating Mode : Advanced EEC Mode (Space to change options)
4. Escape (Esc Key), Save settings and Exit.
5. Reboot (Should be done automatically, if not manually reboot)

All of your memory will show up as usable...
Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Run MSCONFIG in your server.
2. Open the "Boot" tab.
3. Click on "Advanced options".
4. Uncheck the box "maximum memory"
5. Restart

Hope this helps